# What is wrong with my exception handling here?

Tags: c++, exception, pow

I am trying to write a custom function that can raise any number 'a' to the power 'b' and i'm only interested in getting the real portion of my answer. I have written my own function to handle, but it still fails when a is negative. Can any tell me how I go about fixing this, please?

```
#include <exception>
...
double power(double a, double b) {
    double output;
    try {output = pow(a,b);}
    catch (std::domain_error) { //even if I use catch(...) I still get a NaN.
    if (b==0.0) output = 1.0;
    if (a==0.0) output = 0.0;
    if (b<0.0) {
        b=-1.0*b;
        try {output = 1.0/pow(a,b);}
        catch (std::domain_error){ 
        a = -1.0*a;
        output = -1.0/pow(a,b);
        }}
    else {
        a=-1.0*a;
        output = -1.0*pow(a,b);}
    }
    return output;
}
```

Many thanks for the replies. I have read the responses and made the following code.

```
double power(double a, double b) {
    double output;
    output = pow(a,b);
    if (output != output) {
       if (b==0.0) output = 1.0;
       if (a==0.0) output = 0.0;
          else if (b<0.0) {
           b=-1.0*b;
           output = 1.0/pow(a,b);
           if (output != output) { 
           a = -1.0*a;
           output = -1.0/pow(a,b);
           }}
       else {
        a=-1.0*a;
        output = -1.0*pow(a,b);}
    }
    if (output >= DBL_MAX) output = DBL_MAX;
    if (output <= -DBL_MAX) output =-DBL_MAX;
    if ((output >= -DBL_MIN) && (output <= DBL_MIN)) output = 0.0;
    return output;
}
```

My only remaining question is how does c++ handle 1.0/inf? I hope that it will be caught by

```
if ((output >= -DBL_MIN) && (output <= DBL_MIN)) output = 0.0;
```

Comment: Which compiler is used?

Comment: I got no exception on Visual Studio 2012.  From the doc `pow()` is not supposed to raise an exception, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dt5dakze(v=vs.120).aspx

Comment: std::pow doesn't throw afaik.

Comment: I am using VS 2012. Yes, i realise that pow doesn't raise those exceptions and i have rewritten the code.

Answer (score 7):

The floating point arithmetic handling doesn't throw std::exceptions: it just return special values that represent the exception:

In partucular, for the **[std::pow](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow)** function, the documetation says:

> ... 
>   Domain error occurs if base is 0 and exp is less than or equal to ​0​. 
>   NAN is returned in that case
>   ...

It doesn't say that `std::domain_error` is thrown, but that NAN is returned to represent thaat anomaly.

Since no `throw` is made, there is nothing to `catch`.

For your purposes, don't use exceptions: since you know what kind of input you want to handle, just pre-filter it.

Comment: Thanks. I checked for NaNs using x != x and checked for inf by using x >= DBL_MAX. I think that my code is correct now, but do you know how c++ handles 1.0/inf?

Answer (score 2):

Math functions do not throw exceptions - they set special exception flags (more about it in [Floating-point environment](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/fenv), there is even [example](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/fenv/FE_exceptions)).

To check whether your `pow` function failed, either check whether the return value is NAN, or use one of the floating exception functions to do it (assuming you set it properly).